# How to avoid overwriting of CSS media queries for iPad of different viewport sizes

Tags: css, media-queries, styling

I am trying to write CSS to adjust UI for iPad of different viewport sizes like for iPad Pro 11,12, and iPad Air. But styling is overwriting by the last media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {//CSS}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 // CSS
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 //CSS
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 820px) and (max-device-width: 1180px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ 
   //CSS
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 820px) and (max-device-width: 1180px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
  //CSS
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 1194px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
//CSS
 }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 1194px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
  //CSS
}
```

I am expecting that media queries not overwrite and the styles are for which device should only apply for that device.
Note: In my case devices are iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 //CSS
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-width: 1194px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
  //CSS
}
```

Now consider a window that is 1050px wide, portrait and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.

- Does it meet the rule `min-device-width: 1024px`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `max-device-width: 1366px`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `orientation: portrait`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `min-device-width: 834px`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `max-device-width: 1194px`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `orientation: portrait`? Yes
- Does it meet the rule `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2`? Yes

Both media queries match completely.

The rules in **both** will be applied.

Any conflicting rules will be handled by the normal [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-sort) rules which includes, all else being equal, [the order they appear](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-order) in the CSS source code.

---

With your current approach you need to do one or more of:

- Take more care over the order the rules are applied in
- Take more care over the conditions expressed in the media queries

However, it would probably be better to **stop trying to have ultra-device specific rules**.

A popular design philosophy is *mobile first* in which CSS is written for a narrow device and then *selectively overridden* with media queries as more room becomes available. Choose the widths of the media queries based on how much space is needed for the wider design, not what a particular device supports. Website designs tend to last longer than specific pieces of hardware!

Comment: But the device with a minimum width of 1024px also comes under 834px, it would not be overwritten?

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){// CSS} , I guess this would be enough?

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-portrait.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="`ipad-landsc`ape.css" />
```

To reduce HTTP call, this can also be used inside you existing common CSS file:

```
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .ipad-portrait { color: red; } /* your css rules for ipad portrait */
}

@media all and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 768px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .ipad-landscape { color: blue; } /* your css rules for ipad landscape */
}
```